# maven surefire plugin not picking up test

Tags: java, maven

I have a simple Maven project, and have a test class called IntegrationTest.

When I execute: `mvn surefire:test`, the test gets executed. However, the same test is completely ignored when I execute a standard Maven build: `mvn package`

Am I missing anything?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION** (May 24th):

I tried to follow advice by @dragan-bozanovic, but inexplicably, without any changes, my tests are not called under any condition anymore. I'm stumped. I committed a project here: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb
The tests are not invoked in this module: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb/tree/master/activeweb-lessc-integration-test

I tried JUnit 3 style, JUnit4 style, changed names of classes, moved to different package - no avail. When I execute `mvn install`, I  do not see that surefire plugin is called. When I call it explicitly: `mvn surefire:test`, it puts out a message: `No tests to run`

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The real reason for surefire plugin not be able to find tests, is because my `pom.xml` file had `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. As soon as I switched it to `<packaging>jar</packaging>`, surefire plugin picked up the tests. In any case, Dragan - thank you for pushing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

According to Maven default build [lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), integration tests come after the package phase. It may be that a naming convention is used here, because your test class name ends with `IntegrationTest`.

If this is really not an integration test, then rename the class accordingly. If it is, then it seems that Maven behaves as described.

**EDIT**

It may also be that a wrong combination of versions of surefire, JUnit and JUnit-style of tests is used. More info about this can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html).

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it is not that. Please, see extra info I added to the question.

Comment: Could you run mvn install with flag `-Dsurefire.junit4.upgradecheck`?